# Binding img src

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an `img` tag in a Vue component with a binded `src` attribute to Vuex state.

```
<img :src="this.$store.state.imageDataURI">
```

I am successfully updating that state object in Vuex (see below).

However the `img` tag does not get rendered (see below).

I can fix this with getters but just curious as to why this doesn't work. I suspect this has to do with Vue's reactivity model.

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When attaching to bindings, `this` isn't needed and if I'm remembering right can cause issues like this.

Also your store structure looks like you have a module `imageStore` this would namepace of the `imageDataURI` element.

Try:

```
<img :src="$store.state.imageStore.imageDataURI">
```